# GestureDetector: allow onScroll to be called, while not consuming the touch event

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin, touch-event

So I have a layout that's on all over the screen and suppose to catch scroll and fling event wherever they are. Problem is that you can't do it unless you consume the listener, thus, other views' touchListeners will never invoke, and this cannot happen.

An example code will be this:

```
private val onTouchListener = object : View.OnTouchListener {
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        //this block will be reached only once, even when you scroll

        GestureDetector(activity, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
                //is never called
                return false
            }
            override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
                //is never called
                return false
            }
        })

        return false //if this will be 'true', the block will be reached for as long as the touch continues, but touch events bellow it won't invoke
    }
}
```

this is android's comment on this problem. It doesn't seem very fair, to be honest.

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener
> consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have
> multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when
> the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not
> consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions
> from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions
> within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action
> event.

What can I do? thanks